# always include current locale in url route in zend framework 2 (ZF2)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How to include current locale like en, tr, ... in url. you can see like of this in symfony or Joomla.
when use enter to this url: http://test.com this automatically convert to http://test.com/en I want to include current locale in url and recognize it and change the website locale.

Answer (score 0):

in your Module.php file :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{                
    $em = StaticEventManager::getInstance();
    $em->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application', MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'onRoute'), 
}

public function onRoute(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeLang = $e->getRouteMatch()->getParam('lang', false);
    if(!$routeLang)
        $e->getRouter()->setDefaultParam('lang', \Locale::getDefault());
}
```

and your main route config :

```
    'app' => array(
        'type' => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/[:lang]',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                'action' => 'index',
            ),
            'constraints' => array(
                'lang' => '[a-z]{0,2}',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

all the other routes should be a child of this route.